# How to produce a list of all unique key path from a given JSON

Tags: json, path, jq, keypaths

I would like to produce a list of all unique key path from a given JSON, each one in a line.

For example, from this input JSON:

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "id":306,
         "name":"First Company",
         "branches":[
            {
               "id":4191,
               "city":"San Francisco",
               "customers":[
                  {
                     "id":446,
                     "name":"Big Tech 1"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":447,
                     "name":"Big Tech 2"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id":4192,
               "city":"Miami",
               "customers":[
                  {
                     "id":448,
                     "name":"Insurance Tech 1"
                  },
                  {
                     "id":449,
                     "name":"Health Tech 2"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to produce this output:

```
  results
  results.id
  results.name
  results.branches
  results.branches.id
  results.branches.city
  results.branches.customers
  results.branches.customers.id
  results.branches.customers.name
```

I am struggling with the command line below but it is not working.

```
jq '
def path(k):
  if k | type == "object":
    reduce(.keys[] | path(.), k)
  else:
    [k]
;

.[] | path(".") | flatten | sort' example.json
```

Any help, please?

Answer (score 4):

You could `map` the `paths` to only contain `strings`, then drop the duplicates using `unique`, and `join` the items by providing a delimiter:

```bash
jq -r '[paths | map(strings)] | unique[] | join(".")'
```

```json
results
results.branches
results.branches.city
results.branches.customers
results.branches.customers.id
results.branches.customers.name
results.branches.id
results.id
results.name
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/WX5qwPD-n76)

To retain the document order (`unique` also sorts the array), you could deduplicate the list by using the joined paths as (unique-by-definition) object fields instead:

```bash
jq -r '[paths | map(strings) | join(".") | {(.):.}] | add[]'
```

```json
results
results.id
results.name
results.branches
results.branches.id
results.branches.city
results.branches.customers
results.branches.customers.id
results.branches.customers.name
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/mZxtOZ1hpeW)

Answer (score 3):

With `paths` function, filtering out array indices of object keys and collecting unique paths:

```
jq '[paths(.) | map(select(type != "number")) | join(".")] | unique[]' test.json
```

---

```
"results"
"results.branches"
"results.branches.city"
"results.branches.customers"
"results.branches.customers.id"
"results.branches.customers.name"
"results.branches.id"
"results.id"
"results.name"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that outputs the following to make it clear where the arrays are as well:

```
results[]
results[].branches[]
results[].branches[].city
results[].branches[].customers[]
results[].branches[].customers[].id
results[].branches[].customers[].name
results[].branches[].id
results[].id
results[].name
```

This is quite handy to see the "shape" of the JSON quickly before manipulating it.

If you have this code in a script called `show-shape.jq` ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/i5sVvOhxA3h)):

```
#! /usr/local/bin/jq -r -f 

def extract:
    [ paths 
    | [ .[] | if type == "number" then "[]" else . end ] 
    | join (".") ] ;

def longest:
    . | sort_by(length) | reverse| .[0] ; 

def clean:
    [ .[] | gsub("[.][[]]"; "[]") ]  
    | group_by(. | rtrimstr("[]")) 
    | [ .[] | longest ];

def show:
    extract | sort | unique | clean | .[];
    
show
```

You can use it as follows:

```
cat some.json | show-shape.jq
```

Example:

```
§ echo '{"x":{"a":1,"b":[{"c":1},{"c":2}],"d":{"e":1}}}' | show-shape.jq 

x
x.a
x.b[]
x.b[].c
x.d
x.d.e
```

Notice the distinction between how `x.b[].c` and `x.d.e` are displayed.

One shortcoming of the script, thuogh, is that it does not show a trailing `[]` for an empty array:

```
§ echo '{ "a" : [1] }' | show-json-shape.jq 
a[]
§ echo '{ "a" : [] }' | show-json-shape.jq 
a
```